# Retain string formatting in the response from asp.net mvc2 action method

Tags: asp.net, httpresponse

I'm trying to show test run log (text file in a windows server) to the user if he/she clicks a link.

So far I'm able to return the string but the formatting is lost (no newlines) when displayed in the browser.

```
public string GetTestLog(...)
{ 
    return File.ReadAllText(logFileUrl);
}
```

How can I keep the formatting of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return the file with test/plain contentType and then it should render properly as a text file...

```
public ActionResult GetTestLog(...)
{
    return new FileContentResult(File.ReadAllBytes(logFileUrl), "text/plain");
}
```

If you are rendering it as HTML, you have to replace all newlines with `<br/>` or enclose it in a `TEXTAREA` or `PRE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the output inside ah HTML `PRE` tag to preserve the original formatting.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-pre-element.html#the-pre-element